# Material-UI: Prevent Accordion summary vertical movement

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Created this accordion and will use it as a menu item.

However, when I click Main title, accordion summary moves vertically downward.

How can I keep Main tile fixed while opening?

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-accordion-menu-hxc37)

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Typography,
  Grid,
  Accordion,
  AccordionSummary,
  AccordionDetails,
  ListItem
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    panelSummary: {
      flexDirection: "row-reverse",
      paddingLeft: "0px"
    },
    heading: {
      fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(15),
      fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
    },
    innerMenuItem: {
      paddingLeft: "32px"
    },
    expanded: {
      padding: "0px"
    }
  })
);

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Accordion>
      <AccordionSummary
        className={classes.panelSummary}
        expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        aria-controls="panel1a-content"
        id="panel1a-header"
      >
        <Typography className={classes.heading}>Main title</Typography>
      </AccordionSummary>
      <AccordionDetails>
        <Grid container direction="column">
          <ListItem className={classes.innerMenuItem} button key={1}>
            <Typography className={classes.heading}>Sub Item 1</Typography>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem
            className={classes.innerMenuItem}
            button
            key={2}>
            <Typography className={classes.heading}>Sub Item 2</Typography>
          </ListItem>
        </Grid>
      </AccordionDetails>
    </Accordion>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When expanded, the summary's vertical margin is set to some value, you need to reset it if you don't want to see the summary size changes during the expansion:

**V5**

```
<AccordionSummary
  sx={{
    "&.Mui-expanded": {
      minHeight: 0
    },
    "& .MuiAccordionSummary-content.Mui-expanded": {
      // margin from https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/cc0e2ab63e8be9ec4d51a49bfde17ef28fc77b9c/packages/mui-material/src/AccordionSummary/AccordionSummary.js#L64-L64
      margin: "12px 0"
    }
  }}
>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

**V4**

```
panelSummary: {
  "&.Mui-expanded": {
    minHeight: 0
  },
  "& .MuiAccordionSummary-content.Mui-expanded": {
    margin: "auto"
  }
},
```

[image: Edit 67233163/material-ui-accordion-prevent-vertical-movement]

Comment: Thanks, but still there is some vertically change during transition. Am I missing something? Tried margin: "0"  But the same agian.

Comment: @killjoy Sorry, I messed up. You also need to reset `min-height` of `&.Mui-expanded`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can just pass in `disableGutters` as `true` in version 5 of mui

```
<Accordion disableGutters>
 // ....
</Accordion>
```